# Find and Replace Header/Footer text Office JS

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, office-js

I'm having trouble with office js and processing a list of items with lookup codes and replacement values for the header and footer. I've got the body working just not the header/footer. I'm getting this error:`0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: The property 'items' is not available. Before reading the property's value, call the load method on the containing object and call "context.sync()" on the associated request context.` As you can see I do call load and sync before trying to access the results.

```
function mergeHeader(documentFieldKeys) {
    if (documentFieldKeys.length > 0)
        Word.run(function(context) {
            var key = documentFieldKeys.shift();
            var mySections = context.document.sections;
            context.load(mySections, 'body/style');
            return context.sync().then(function() {
                for (var i = 0; i < mySections.items.length; i++ ) {
                    findAndReplace(key, context, mySections.items[i].getHeader("primary"));
                }

                return context.sync().then(function() {
                        return mergeHeader(documentFieldKeys);
                    })
                    .then(context.sync);
            });
        });
}

function findAndReplace(key, context, body) {
    var results = body.search(key.Code, { matchWholeWord: false, matchCase: false });
    context.load(results);
    return context.sync().then(function() {
            if (results.items.length > 0 && key.Value === "") {
                missingFields.push(key.Description);
            } else {
                for (var i = 0; i < results.items.length; i++) {
                    results.items[i].insertText(key.Value, "replace");
                }
            }
        })
        .then(context.sync);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
 context.load(mySections, 'items');
```

or

```
mySections.load('items');
```

Comment: I updated the mergeHeader function with the recommended change and still getting the same error.

Comment: @CJFravel Did you use Nick's suggestion literally, or did you substitute the properties you want to load for "items"?

Comment: Would this also work to find out whether a text selection is in header/footer instead of in body?